# Can't login with WinForms app to IdentityServer4 using IdentityModel.OidcClient2

Tags: identityserver4

I get an invalid grant when I try to login from my WinForms app to IS4.

This is the server log:

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Unexpected code_verifier: 12a783b32873a5b4ae0eb7113a067cd978d3d345a8cb29cc0a1a6df131c5839a 
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "las",
        "ClientName": "LAS.NET Client",
        "GrantType": "authorization_code",
        "AuthorizationCode": "e301575cc20f47acf7c15178310f776642a7a30cf2b6a05f54702097b1645b7a",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "authorization_code",
          "code": "e301575cc20f47acf7c15178310f776642a7a30cf2b6a05f54702097b1645b7a",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost/winforms.client",
          "code_verifier": "12a783b32873a5b4ae0eb7113a067cd978d3d345a8cb29cc0a1a6df131c5839a",
          "client_id": "las",
          "client_secret": "secret"
        }
      }
```

The `LoginResult.Error` says "invalid_grant".

This is the client setup:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "las",
    ClientName = "LAS.NET Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,



ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
        "api1"
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost/winforms.client" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,                  
    RequireConsent = false
},
```

and this is how I initialize my winform app:

```
var options = new OidcClientOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    ClientId = "las",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost/winforms.client",
    Scope = "openid profile api1 offline_access",       
    Browser = new WinFormsEmbeddedBrowser(),
    Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid
};

_oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is `authorization_code` Grant Type apart of `HybridAndClientCredentials`

Comment: @johnny5 Hybrid is a super set of authorization code grant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WinForms client is telling IdentityServer that it wants to do PKCE however the client does not look like it requires PKCE. In your client configuration/setup add `RequirePkce = true`.